# Python garbage collector not working as expected?

Tags: logging, garbage-collection

I have some scripts that are doing our italian mail import,xml extraction, pdfcreation.
Now, they all run in an loop, and if they die, they will be resurected by an p2m process.

So far, so good.
now, those 3 scripts use this at the start of every loop:

```
dbHelper = DbHelper()
logger = Logger("xmlExtract",config('PATHLOGGINGXMLEXTRACT'))
dbHelper.addLogger(logger)
```

If they loop on and on, evertyime they loop, the loggging messages will increase by the numbers the loop was running and I really struggle to understand why?

I tried 2 approaches that came to mind -->

1)

```
dbhelper = None
logger = None
```

remove every refernce on the logger per loop, but it's not working.

2)
making it a singleton (can't provide the code, because I discarded it already since its not working)

My loggingg class:

```
import logging
import os
from dataclasses import dataclass
import inspect

@dataclass
class Logger:

    moduleName: str
    path: str = ""
    valDict = {}
    _instances = {}
    
    def __init__(self, moduleName, path = "../logging/"):
        """[A module that's doing the logging part. Create an instance and call the functions as needed]

        Args:
            moduleName ([str]): [The current module you're using the logger in, determines the logfile name]
            path (str, optional): [the path for the outputfiles]. Defaults to "../logging/".
        """
        self.moduleName = moduleName
        self.path = path

        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('T:%(asctime)s Msg: %(message)s')

        #----------------- Error logger -------------------
        self.__error_logger = logging.getLogger("error")
        self.__error_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

        # File output
        fhandler = logging.FileHandler(filename= path + moduleName + '_error.log', mode='a')
        fhandler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        fhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.__error_logger.addHandler(fhandler)
        
        # Print in console
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.__error_logger.addHandler(handler)
        
        #----------------- Info logger -------------------
        self.__info_logger = logging.getLogger("info")
        self.__info_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # File output
        fhandler = logging.FileHandler(filename= path + moduleName + '_info.log', mode='a')
        fhandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        fhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.__info_logger.addHandler(fhandler)
        
        # Print in console
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.__info_logger.addHandler(handler)
    
    def __new__(cls,moduleName, path = "../logging/"):
        # Return instance if there is already one present to reduce number of db sessions
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Logger, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instances[cls]

    def errorLog(self, errorMessage, exceptionText =""):
        """[Appends a error message to the given logfile]

        Args:
            errorMessage ([type]): [The error message / exception text]
            exceptionText (str, optional): [The excptiontext that is thrown]. Defaults to "".
        """
         # get FunctionName
        functionName = inspect.stack()[1][3]

        errorMessage = f"Error in Module: {self.moduleName} | {errorMessage} "
        errorMessage = errorMessage + f"| FUNCTION: {functionName} "
        errorMessage += " | ".join([f"{key} : {value}" for key,value in self.valDict.items()])
        errorMessage = errorMessage + f"--> {exceptionText}" if exceptionText else errorMessage
        self.__error_logger.error(errorMessage)
        

    def infoLog(self, infoMessage):
        """[Appends a info message to the given logfile]

        Args:
            infoMessage ([type]):  [The info message / exception text]
        """
        # get FunctionName
        functionName = inspect.stack()[1][3]
        
        infoMessage = f"Info Module: {self.moduleName} | {infoMessage} "
        infoMessage = infoMessage + f"| FUNCTION: {functionName} "
        infoMessage += " | ".join([f"{key} : {value}" for key,value in self.valDict.items()])
        self.__info_logger.info(infoMessage)
```

I really need adivce, struggling with that for some hours now and have no idea what to do ;(

As far as I know there is a garage collecor? But it's not working because I did something wrong, ut I really dont know what ;(